# How to create a loop without knowing when the loop will stop?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program which takes a number and we match that number with a variable which has a specific number stored. We need to keep doing that until the user enters the correct number that matches the number we have stored in our variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        int i;
        int j;
        int num1;
        int num2 = 2;

        printf("Enter number");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        while (num1 == 0) {

                printf("Enter number");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
        }

        while (num1 != num2) {

                for(j=1;j
                printf("This is not the correct number! \n");
                printf("Enter number again: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
        }

        if (num1 == num2) {

                printf("The numbers have matched! \n");
        }
}
```

I am confused with how do we create a loop where we don't know how many times the user will enter an incorrect number. What I want with the loop is to display
is how many times the user enters an incorrect number. Let say if they enter 3 times.

```
    This is not the correct number 1!
    This is not the correct number 2!
    This is not the correct number 3!
```

But we don't know how many times the user will enter an incorrect number, so what condition do I put in a loop, so it counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a separate counter variable that keeps track of how many times you've gone through the loop.  Set it to 0 before the loop, then increment on each iteration.

```
   int count = 0;
   ...
   while (num1 != num2) {
            count++;
            printf("This is not the correct number %d! \n", count);
            printf("Enter number again: ");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
    }
```

Also, I'm presuming this is a typo:

```
for(j=1;j
```